# jar file made in ubuntu does not work in windows

Tags: java, ubuntu, junit, jar

I wrote a code in Windows using Eclipse. The code used JUnit. I converted it to a .jar file Ubuntu. However, when I try to open the .jar file in Windows in Eclipse, the code does not open. Instead of code, I see some random characters in Eclipse.

Comment: Why do you go to Ubuntu to create the .jar file? If you write the code in Windows and deploy it on Windows, can't you just create the .jar in Windows too?

Comment: SomeClass.jar != SomeClass.java :)

Comment: I couldn't. Even if I set PATH, the "jar" command was unknown to the prompt. @nick

Comment: Do you mean that it is normal for me to see that? If so, how do I run the .jar file in Eclipse? @djjolem

Comment: You don't run .jar files in eclipse. Jar files are like zip files, they are multiple files all compressed together.  Java uses the .jar to keep all your .class files in the same place for running.

Comment: So how do I run the .jar in Windows? @nick

Comment: I'm rusty on the windows command but its something like java -jar *your file*

Comment: as @nick saud you don't run .jar file in eclipse. You can import .jar file in project. If you want run .jar in Win use java -jar JarName.jar.

Answer (score 0):

JAR files are a collection of compiled java files (.class), if you want the source code to open in eclipse just copy over the .java files